# Does Npgsql provider has support for TransactionScope?

Tags: npgsql

I'm trying to use a TransactionScope with the Npgsql provider.
I found in an old question ([provider for PostgreSQL in .net with support for TransactionScope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819569/provider-for-postgresql-in-net-with-support-for-transactionscope)) that Npgsql didn't supported it yet.
Now, after about 5 years, does Npgsql support TransactionScope?
I made a test for myself, using Npgsql 3.0.3 and using the following code:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using(var connection = new Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=*****;password=*****database=test;CommandTimeout=0"))
    {
        connection.Open();

        var command = new NpgsqlCommand(@"insert into test.table1 values ('{10,20,30}', 2);");
        command.Connection = connection;
        var result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // scope.Complete();  <-- Not committed
    }
}
```

Anyone can confirm that Npgsql doesn't support TransactionScope?

**EDIT #1**
After the confirmation of the support of Npgsql to the TransactionScope, I found that you need to be sure to haev Distribuited Transaction enabled in your PostgreSQL configuration, checking the *max_prepared_transactions* parameter in the *postgres.conf* file (remember to restart your server).

**EDIT #2**
I enabled the Distribuited Transaction on my server but now I got an error using the TransactionScope with Npgsql.
This is my code:

```
using (var sourceDbConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(SourceConnectionString))
using (var destinationDbConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(DestinationConnectionString))
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        sourceDbConnection.Open();
        destinationDbConnection.Open();

        Logger.Info("Moving data for the {0} table.", TableName.ToUpper());
        var innerStopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        innerStopWatch.Start();

        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            var etlEntity = new EtlInfoItem
            {
                MigratedEntityId = category.RowId,
                ProjectId = category.ProjectId,
                ExecutionDatetime = DateTime.Now
            };

            // Insert into the destination database
            var isRowMigrated = InsertEntity(entity, DestinationSchema, destinationDbConnection);

            if (isRowMigrated)
            {
                // Update the ETL migration table
                InsertCompletedEtlMigrationEntity(etlEntity, EtlSchema, sourceDbConnection);
            }
            else
            {
                // Update the ETL migration table
                InsertFailedEtlMigrationEntity(etlEntity, EtlSchema, sourceDbConnection);
            }
        }

        Logger.Info("Data moved in {0} sec.", innerStopWatch.Elapsed);

        Logger.Info("Committing transaction to the source database");
                innerStopWatch.Restart();

        scope.Complete();

        innerStopWatch.Stop();
        Logger.Info("Transaction committed in {0} sec.", innerStopWatch.Elapsed);
    }
```

When the TransactionScope exits from the scope (when exiting the using statement), I get a Null Reference Exception with the following stack trace:
Server stack trace:
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Cleanup()
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Break()
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadSingleMessage(DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean returnNullForAsyncMessage)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadExpectingT
.........
It happens randomly.

Comment: In my tests, this does not need a non-zero *max_prepared_transactions*. I have it working (passing a refcursor parameter from one command to another) using `Enlist=true` in the connection string, with *max_prepared_transactions* at zero.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Npgsql does support TransactionScope and has done so for quite a while. However, at least for the moment, in order to have your connection participate in the TransactionScope you must either:

1. Include `Enlist=true` in your connection string, or
2. Call NpgsqlConnection.EnlistTransaction

Take a look at the [Npgsql unit tests](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/7ca02e99977deab9c0dafc142e4ddd3f55eb995e/test/Npgsql.Tests/SystemTransactionTests.cs) around this for some examples.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now I have another issue. You can find a description in my post, in the Edit #2 part.

Comment: Can you please open an issue for this?

Comment: For new visitor, this is not required anymore since it's the default now