# C# - using TransactionScope while inserting into two DB tables

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

I need to insert into two database tables. Is it a good options to use TransactionScope in C#.

```
using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
{
FilterOption.Insert(int operator, int value);
MainTable.Insert(int a1, int b1, string c1);
}
```

I'm using postGreSql as DBMS with in line query. I'm not sure how to pass table values into postGreSQL stored procedure. However, I'd like to have the atomicity of this transaction. is it a good idea to use TransactionScope here?

Thank you.

Comment: You're going to want to call `transactionScope.Complete()` before exiting the `using` block.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot. oh yes. But my concern here is, if first insert executed and 2nd fails. I've to rollback the 1st inserted values.

Comment: If the second operation fails, you shouldn't complete the transaction, and the transaction manager would rollback the entire transaction. Assuming you are using the Npgsql provider for postgres, [you'll need to ensure your connections participate in the transaction](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33592757/21418), and looking at Github there have been a few issues in the past with the provider's support for enlisting in transcations using `TransactionScope`, so you may want to test your scenarios regardless, but overall, assuming happy path, this is exactly the intended usage of the class.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot got it. Thanks for all the information.. :)